# how to change PaginatorHelper direction

Tags: cakephp, pagination

how to change PaginatorHelper direction? it's generated links sort `asc`, and i want to change in to `desc`.
i wrote that code at my .ctp file, but no changes..:

```
<?php $this->Paginator->options(array('direction' => 'desc')) ?>
```

how to change that direction? can I change it in controller? or i should change at view?
my helpers:

```
public $helpers = array ('Html', 'Form', 'Paginator');
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting defaults for pagination is outlines in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1232/Controller-Setup). You can also pass params to the `paginate()` call in your controller:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Recipe.title LIKE' => 'a%'),
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => 'Recipe.created'
);
```

Comment: thanks, but i think your code set default order to `Recipe.created`, ascending. how to change the default sorting to descending?

Comment: @Dunhamzzz your solution does not set the generated pagination link to DESC as the OP is asking, it only pre-sorts the data returned by the pagination. If you were to click on a pagination link, it would default the direction to ASC still. Arrogant comments only portrays ego, it does not provide solutions. 1) the manual is not clear on how to set the default sort direction, 2) don't assume that because someone doesn't have the knowledge you do that they haven't read the manual, and 3) at least attempt to understand the question before calling someone out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response, but I wanted to answer the question in case someone comes here looking for the correct answer as there has been no answers that are correct.

To change the default of the pagination `direction` in the paginator, there are two ways you can make this happen.

**The Helper**

If you are using the PaginatorHelper, you can set the default when you create the link in the view:

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('Link Name', 'Model.columnName', array('direction' => 'desc')) ;
```

This will print the link that will sort the column based on the direction you identify in the options array as indicated above. If the options array is left out, it will default to 'asc'.

**The Component**

If you want to set the default direction on the PaginatorComponent, you do so like this:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'direction' => 'desc',
    'sort' => 'Model.column',
);
```

Keep in mind this does two things. It will automatically sort your data by the Model.column identified in the sort option and it will do it in the direction specified.

NOTE: You cannot simply add the direction. It requires BOTH to be set in order to work.